# Laravel 405 method not allowed in server issue

Tags: php, laravel, server

This is my api route:
`Route::post('/addproduct','BannerController@store')->name('addProduct');`

This is my html code:

```
 <form  method="post" action="{{ route('addProduct') }}" id="productForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <div class="row">      
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <select class="form-css" name="staff" id="prod_staff">
                        <option value="0">Select staff</option>
                </select>
                <div class="invalid-error"> 
                    <span class="invalid-staff"></span>                                   
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>


            <h3>Customer Details</h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <select class="form-css" name="customerNumber" id="prod_cust_numb">
                        <option value="0">Select Customer Contact</option>
                </select>
                <div class="invalid-error"> 
                   <span class="invalid-cust_numb"></span>                                   
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-css" readonly name="customerName" id="prod_cust_name" placeholder="Customer Name">
                <div class="invalid-error"> 
                   <span class="invalid-cust_name"></span>                                   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitProduct">Submit</button>
</form>
```

While using FormData in server got an issue ;
while using Form.serialize() there's no issue in server
"This is my javascript":

```
<script>$('#productForm').on('submit',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
let thiss=$(this);
let form = document.getElementById('productForm');
let data =new FormData(form); 
$.ajax({        
        type:thiss.attr('method'),
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        url:thiss.attr('action'),
        data:data,
        dataType:'JSON',
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
});});</script>
```

Localhost works smoothly Issue are in Serverside Linux hosting
This is my server images

[image]

[image]

Comment: which Route you are using? web.php or api.php

Comment: API route using

Comment: csrf token is not passing correclty

Comment: No error for csrf in server

Comment: Found error due to FormData need solution for FormData. Works fine for form.serialize in server tested

Comment: On server side token is not passing correclty brother

Comment: Add this code before `$.ajax` before formData. and comment your header portion and check if it works, `$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});`

Comment: Sir, i tried your code for ajaxSetup won't work still 405 error, Interesting fact I hide the whole csrf from the form and ajax it won't give me csrf token issue

Comment: comment `contentType: false` for a while and also set `Content-Type: application/json` while sending request to api. And check if it works

Comment: Worked Sir @akhtar but,i cant get data on the controller side due to contentType... but,there's no issue 405 on server side

Comment: Okay now un-comment `contentType: false` and set same `Content-Type: application/json` from your request and check again for data.

Comment: I'm getting data in controller like this format : i debug using   dd($request->getContent());
`------WebKitFormBoundarybJ8HJ8leN4q107GD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_token"
oTcowxn0DcS7LsbZKF6UAf6VqkoZfAmcGFOIMnxF
------WebKitFormBoundarybJ8HJ8leN4q107GD
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="staff"
4`

Comment: what you get when you `dd($request->all())`

Comment: getting :[] sir could you please give a call no this number:9930860396 i need to solve this server error...please

Comment: I can't call for now sorry, comment these lines for a while and check `dataType:'JSON'` , `cache: false` and `processData: false,`

Comment: commented 3 of them and got illegal Innvocation error on console

Comment: have you set it in this way `Content-Type: application/json` ?

Comment: no, this way--> contentType:'application/json';

Comment: Content-Type: application/json Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '-'

Comment: so it is an api route ? have you made this api route by yourself ? if yes, then have you tested it on postman ?

Comment: Yes made by me, i never used postman